# Check for missing driver for Dynamic Backlight Control (DBC)

Tags: drivers, gnome, backlight

Gnome should support an automatic screen brigthness feature, which can be set in gnome-control-center.

This adaptive brightness might not be supported on all computer. If so, the relative setting is not shown. That's my case with my Dell XPS 9360. I thought that was not supported on my latop, but I googled a bit and it seems that it's not the case. This laptop should support such feature.

Do I need to install some additional driver? How to check if this DBC is truly supported in my system?

Thank you!